# Can't set bold weight for fonts

Tags: faces, fonts

I trying make the variable-pitch font weight to be bold, as I find the variable-pitch font be very thin and almost not visible clearly, but it doesn't seem to work for neither default nor fixed-pitch either. Not sure why is the case though, because with similar configuration `doom-emacs` version looks fine with same color scheme, font family, size and weight.

Here is a screenshot for how the `variable-pitch` font looks visually and also the my font configuration.

[image]

I am using the tomorrow night color scheme.

Comment: Some fonts (and thus some face attributes), `bold` in particular, are not supported for some faces/fonts. Try another variable-pitch font, which you know supports `bold`.

Comment: Both `Fira Code` and `Cantarell` font have `bold` versions. BTW I fixed the issue. I was modifying the `org` specific faces later in the `init.el` file that's  why I was not seeing the changes.

Comment: Please consider doing one of these things: (1) post your answer as an answer (you can accept your own answer), if you think the question and answer might help others, or (2) delete the question, if you don't think the Q & A are useful for others. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Fira Code` and `Cantarell` font have bold versions.

BTW I fixed the issue. I was modifying the org specific faces later in the `init.el` file and I had the `weight` set to `regular` for those faces, that's why I was not seeing the changes, because it was probably overriding my changes.

So I consider this as solved now.